# Real-time face recognition: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to work out on real-time face recognition using OpenCV and Python, but in training the dataset/training images, I got a permission error. I don't know what is the problem in the code. I had finished detecting the face and gathering data but when running the below code, I received this error.

Here is my code:

```
path = 'C:\MyComputer\Data Science\Works\FaceRecognition\Dataset'

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml');

def getImagesAndLabels(path):

    imagePaths = [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path)]  
    faceSamples=[]
    ids = []

    for imagePath in imagePaths:

        PIL_img = Image.open(imagePath).convert('L')
        
        img_numpy = np.array(PIL_img,'uint8')

        id = int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split(".")[1])
        faces = detector.detectMultiScale(img_numpy)

        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            faceSamples.append(img_numpy[y:y+h,x:x+w])
            ids.append(id)

    return faceSamples,ids

print ("\n [INFO] Training faces. It will take a few seconds. Wait ...")
faces,ids = getImagesAndLabels(path)
recognizer.train(faces, np.array(ids))

recognizer.write('trainer/trainer.yml') 

print("\n [INFO] {0} faces trained. Exiting Program".format(len(np.unique(ids))))
```

I wrote this code by referring to [this tutorial](https://www.instructables.com/id/Real-time-Face-Recognition-an-End-to-end-Project/#:%7E:text=OpenCV%20was%20designed%20for%20computational,Face%20Detection%20and%20Data%20Gathering)

The error is:

```
PIL_img = Image.open(imagePath).convert('L')

  File "C:\Users\nadha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2809, in open
  fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")

  PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\MyComputer\\DataScience\\Works\\FaceRecognition\\Dataset\\TrainedData'
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a simple file system access permission problem. If you are using Windows:

- Right-click the file
- Select "Properties"
- Click on the tab "Security"
- Select your user in the list, and set permission to "Full Permission"

The same goes for folders. You can find a more detailed instruction [in this link](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/set-file-folder-permissions-windows/).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to run real time face recognition within deepface because of its simplicity. You just need to pass the facial database path. It wraps state-of-the-art face recognition models such as VGG-Face (University of Oxford), Facenet (Google), OpenFace (Carnegie Mellon University), DeepFace (Facebook), DeepID (The Chinese University of Hong Kong) and Dlib.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace

db_path = "C:/my_db" #you should store facial images in this directory

DeepFace.stream(db_path = db_path
   , model_name = 'VGG-Face' #candidates are VGG-Face, Facenet, OpenFace, DeepFace, DeepID and Dlib
   , enable_face_analysis = False #set True if to analyze emotion, age and gender
)
```